# Datetimepicker considerando dia como mês

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

Tenho um inputText que criei para data, ele é inicialmente preenchido com um DateTime do meu Model que está populado:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Data, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control input-md", @id = "datetimepickerDataFato" })
```

E meu javascript do datetimepicker

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#datetimepickerDataFato').datetimepicker({
     locale: 'pt-br',
     format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
     allowInputToggle: true,
     maxDate: Date.now()
  });
});
```

O meu problema é que quando esse código javascript do datetimepicker é lido, ele sobrepõe a minha data para o dia de hoje, e ainda considera o dia como se fosse mês, ou seja, não posso colocar nenhum dia que seja maior que 12.

Comment: Você tem 'pt-br' no seu arquivo de locale? Tentou também incluir `language: 'pt'`?

Comment: @RicardoPontual Tem o 'pt-br' no locale sim. Tentei fazer o esquema do language mas também não deu certo

Answer (score 0):

Tente utilizar o seguinte formato: 'dd/MM/yyyy' no seu javascript.

Comment: Eu tentei, mas ele traz o ordinal do dia da semana, tipo 5ª, 6ª

Comment: Isso já está no datapicker, o que você quer dizer com "*no seu javascript*"? O código do datapicker já está no javascript, resposta confusa e superficial, coloque mais detalhes e um exemplo de código. O conteúdo atual da sua resposta poderia ser um simples comentário.